# Simple Unit Test for an invalid byte sequence fails (What is the correct way to structure the test?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, utf-8

I am writing a simple unit test that is supposed to convert a value in a database from ASCII to UTF8 with the Rails after_find callback. This is my simple test code:

```
  def test_convert_edit_value_into_utf8 
    edit = edits(:edit_with_invalid_byte_sequence)
    assert_equal "This is a string with invalid byte sequence", edit
  end
```

FYI I have also tried this variation for testing.
    def test_convert_edit_value_into_utf8 
      edit = edits(:edit_with_invalid_byte_sequence)
      assert_equal "This is a string with invalid byte sequence", edit
    end

In my fixtures file, this entry is being extracted for the above test(shown below):

```
edit_with_invalid_byte_sequence:
  id: 8
  type: PropertyEdit
  target_id: 1
  target_type: Project
  key: description
  value: "This is a string with invalid byte sequence\255"
  account_id: 1
```

As you can see, I've inserted an invalid byte sequence on the value line of edit_with_invalid_byte_sequence. The after_find method that I have corrects for this but when I run the test I receive this error.

`Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): found unknown escape character while parsing a quoted scalar at line 61 column 10`

The error is referring to the aforementioned value line of edit_with_invalid_byte_sequence.

What I don't get is how I'm supposed to test for invalid byte sequence when Rails cannot load this error to be corrected. I intentionally want that invalid byte sequence so that this code below fixes it.

```
 def after_find
    value.fix_encoding_if_invalid! if value
  end
```

How do I get around this problem, I was following this guide by Thoughtbot [Thoughbot UTF8 byte testing](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/fight-back-utf-8-invalid-byte-sequences)but am not experiencing the desired results. Can someone please point out to me what I am doing wrong. Much appreciated.

Comment: not quite understood, which feature do you wish to test

Comment: I'm trying to test the after_find method for correctly encoding an ASCII string into UTF8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with Yaml, and the way it interprets string literals. It doesn't seem to allow the construction `\255`. Because Yaml expects UTF-8, it may not be possible to insert an invalid UTF-8 character in a Yaml document.

I would recommend just setting the parameter in the test itself. i.e.

```
edit.value = "This is a string with invalid byte sequence\255"
```

Also, IMO factories are a better way of generating test data than fixtures.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Slicedpan, I tried what you recommended and I progressed thorugh the test with a different error. I wanted to ask you though. Do callbacks work on test files as well? Will my after_find method when I run my test?

Comment: Usually you would create the object using the factory, then call find. Have a look [here](http://pastebin.com/3tzhBwkN) for an example